# PHP regex to remove multiple ?-marks

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I'm having trouble coming up with the correct regex string to remove a sequence of multiple ? characters. I want to replace more than one sequential ? with a single ?, but which characters to escape...is escaping me.

Example input:

> Is this thing on??? or what???

Desired output:

> Is this thing on? or what?

I'm using [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) in PHP.

Comment: +1 for reducing the number of question marks blocks on earth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
preg_replace('{\?+}', '?', 'Is this thing on??? or what???');
```

That is, you only have to escape the question mark, the plus in "\?+" means that we're replacing every instance with one or more characters, though I suspect "\?{2,}" might be even better and more efficient (replacing every instance with two or more question mark characters.

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace( '{\\?+}', '?', $text );`

should do it.

You need to escape the question mark itself with a backslash, and then escape the backslash itself with another backslash.

It's situations like this where C#'s [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx) are nice.

Comment: You don't need to escape the backslash in a single quoted string. You can if you want, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (I have tested it):

```
preg_replace('/\?+/', '?', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\?{2,}/','?',$text)
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do it

```
preg_replace('/(\?+)/m', '?', 'what is going in here????');
```

the question mark needs to be escaped and the m is for multiline mode.

This was a good web site to try it out at http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the pattern

```
[?]+
```

with the replacement of `?` ?

Comment: `?` in a character class is considered as a literal question mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace('??', '?', 'Replace ??? in this text');
```

Comment: The output of this will be "Replace ?? in this text", unless you put it in a while-loop, and if you do that it'll suddenly be a whole lot less efficient than preg_replace. On my test server, running this, in a loop, 1m times, took (roughly) 2.7 seconds (roughly), whereas the preg_replace only took 1.2 seconds.